# php oci8 enabled but not doing anything - Redhat linux server

Tags: php, linux, oracle, redhat

I am writing a web app using html and php.

My app requires oci8 to be enabled and to be making connections to an oracle database.

oci8 library is installed and is available. But the oci8 datbase calls do not seem to be working and I receive no php error messages.

This was what was on the php myinfo() reading:

```
oci8
OCI8 Support    enabled
Version     1.4.9
Revision    $Id: e2241cffb72c940cb2ca267b7a6a0ce436de7e5e $
Active Persistent Connections   0
Active Connections  0
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version  11.2.0.3.0
Oracle Instant Client Version   11.2
Temporary Lob support   enabled
Collections support     enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
oci8.connection_class   no value    no value
oci8.default_prefetch   100 100
oci8.events Off Off
oci8.max_persistent -1  -1
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics    Off Off
oci8.persistent_timeout -1  -1
oci8.ping_interval  60  60
oci8.privileged_connect Off Off
oci8.statement_cache_size   20  20
```

Is there anything wrong? What could be the reason for it to suddenly stop working?

Any help here would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Which version of the oracle client drivers are installed on that machine?

Comment: 11g, so I use the oci8 library